# What happened to Edmure Tully after the Red Wedding?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

All the soldiers and commanders from Tully and Stark family were killed during the bedding ceremony of Edmure Tully. What was his fate after this massacre?

Did Walder Frey got his own son in law killed in his bedding ceremony in front of his daughter? Or he left him as he is now family?

If he is alive, what about his married life, is he living with his wife?

Comment: In the books, they kept Edmure as a hostage, but kept him well.  They eventually traded him back for concessions in power.

Comment: @AndrewThompson not sure about "kept him well", if I remember right he spent all day, every day stuck up on a platform with a noose around his neck as an empty threat that he'd be hung if the Tully rebels didn't surrender. And they didn't exactly trade him back, they kept him as what cde below calls a "slave/vassal", in case of future rebellion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last mention of Edmure was in Season 3 episode 10 "**Mhysa**".

> [Look at us now, Tully. You're dead, your daughter's dead, your grandson's dead, **your son spent his wedding night in a dungeon** and I'm Lord of Riverrun. -Walder Frey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3PXs9rfQFg)

There has been no further mention of him, or Blackfish, or the Tullys at all in following seasons of the show, which have departed from following the books closely.

In the books A Storm of Swords match Season 3's treatment of Edmure. The following book, A Feast of Crows, has Edmure as a prisoner, used as a bait for the remaining Tullys, then given an ultimatum to turn over Riverrun, or have it and his to-be-born child destroyed. He turns it over, and now lives as a slave/vassal of the Lannisters.